# ¿Qué se necesita para que una aplicación en lenguaje Java pueda reconocer/leer un tipo de archivo?

Tags: java, archivo

Verán, quisiera hacer una aplicación la cual, mediante un botón, me permita buscar un archivo, por ejemplo, con extensión ".docx"(de documentos de word) o ".sqlite", en el equipo y abrirlo y mostrarlo en mi aplicación. Entonces, ¿qué se requiere para que la aplicación pueda reconocer el tipo de archivo tales archivos, o cualquier otro formato, alguna librería o plugging? Agradeceré que me orienten un poco en este aspecto. Gracias.

Comment: **[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org)** es tu librería. Es la más utilizada para tales fines.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya veo que sí, sirve para las aplicaciones de microsft :D

Comment: Cómo se pueden buscar librerías para otro tipos de formatos?

Comment: Revisa en la documentación  los diferentes formatos que soporta la librería. ¿Dijiste `sqlite`? ¿En ese caso no será mejor implementar la base de datos en sí?

Comment: No necesariamente busco que la aplicación esté vinculada a una base de datos de SQLite, sino que la aplicación pueda abrir estos archivos para ver qué tablas contiene cierta BD.

Comment: Con respecto a `sqlite` me pregunto si no sería ya forzar demasiado la situación. Quizá sea mejor hacer una exportación desde la base de datos a un archivo de texto o algo así, en vez de recurrir a procedimientos oscuros para leer archivos que existen para fines específicos, sin contar con el riesgo que podría suponer intentar leer esos archivos fuera de su entorno (corrupción del archivo y consecuente pérdida de datos por ejemplo).

Comment: Ya veo, sí, tienes razón. De todos modos lo del apache POI me sirve bastante. Gracias.